# NGRX selector triggers on key-value object change

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I've been working with Ngrx for a while now, and I've encountered a little issue.

I have an object in my store, which holds pairings of recipeId-thumbnailURL:

```
recipeIdThumbnailPairs: { [recipeId: string]: string }
```

The thumbnail is stored this way, because it's not actually recipes thumbnail but rather the "newest photo in recipes photos gallery".

problem appears, when I add a new recipe to the base. I'd like to add a new pair to the existing object, but obviously, since we work with Redux pattern, I have to clone the entire object.
This triggers change on all selectors which access thumbnail for each specific recipe - this causes all thumbnails to re-render, because they think they were changed!

1. Does anyone have any idea how to work around this behaviour?
2. Is storing mutable things as key-value pairs in object a bad thing?
3. Wouldn't the same happen if it was a simple array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone have any idea how to work around this behaviour?

Ok so the re-rendering can be caused by a few things.
If you are rendering lists, it always makes sense to use the `trackBy` function so that updating a single item will not cause the whole list to rerender:

https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

Then, to prevent each thumbnail from rerendering you can also create a component which has a string as `@Input` and give that component `ChangeDetectionStratagey.OnPush`. That will make it so that the component only re-renders if an input changes or it receives an event.

> Is storing mutable things as key-value pairs in object a bad thing?

No, not necessearily, but this can make it a lot easier:
https://ngrx.io/guide/entity

> Wouldn't the same happen if it was a simple array?

Yes, I believe so. In fact, since I guess you are iterating somewhere with `ngFor` that makes it an array anyways in the eyes of the renderer.

Comment: Thanks for that!
Yes, turns out the trackBy was the solution - I just had 3 nested NgFors, and each of them needed it's own trackby function - I only tested it on the deepest one, which was a mistake, because "higher ngFors" were forcing rerendering.

Comment: Glad it helped :)